# Node.JS UnhandledException with a HTTPS request

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I need some help trying to stop node from throwing this error, or at-least understand why I can't seem to be able to catch it:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: socket hang up
at SecurePair.error (tls.js:999:23)
at EncryptedStream.CryptoStream._done (tls.js:695:22)
at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:496:24)
at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
at EncryptedStream.onCryptoStreamFinish (tls.js:301:47)
at EncryptedStream.g (events.js:175:14)
at EncryptedStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:354:12)
at endWritable (_stream_writable.js:361:3)
at EncryptedStream.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:339:5)
at EncryptedStream.CryptoStream.end (tls.js:633:31)
at Socket.onend (_stream_readable.js:483:10)
```

This is the code snippet that causes the error:

```
var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  var buffer = '';
  res.on('data', function(data) {
    buffer += data;
  });
  res.on('end', function() {
    try {
      var json = JSON.parse(buffer);
    } catch (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    callback(null, json);
  });
});
req.on('error', function(err) {
  callback(err);
});
req.end(data);

api.prototype._get = function(action, callback, args) {
  args = _.compactObject(args);
  var path = '/api/' + action + '/?' + querystring.stringify(args);
  this._request('get', path, undefined, callback, args)
}

api.prototype._post = function(action, callback, args) {
  var path = '/api/' + action + '/';
  args = _.compactObject(args);
  var data = querystring.stringify(args);
  this._request('post', path, data, callback, args);
}
```

Why isn't req.on('error' catching this err?

Node version: 0.10.21

Comment: A socket hang up is when the server you're trying to contact never ends the connection, and instead a timeout happens, and it responds with a "hang up" error. You have to either figure out why the server isn't closing the connection, or if the request simply takes too long, you have to extend the timeout limit. You are calling `req.end(data)` at the end there, and your variable is called `req` so that should end the request almost before it starts, as requests are async it seems like that is an error, but there's not enough context to tell really.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using the `req` variable name twice ?

Comment: This error probably occurs when the server that I'm trying to contact is temporarily down. So I'm sending a basic get request and when the data is in, I process it. Sometimes it happens that the server I'm connecting to is down, but that doesn't matter to me as I'll just retry ever minute. I'm just trying to stop the error from being thrown. Is there a way for me to catch the timeout err?

Comment: No, I'm not using the req variable twice. Also this script can run fine for over 24 hours and then this error shows up.

Comment: okay, it just seemed a little weird, as you have `data` returned in a callback for an async method, and then at the end you outout `data`, but there shouldn't really be any `data` at that point as it's async etc. To avoid errors, you can stick the entire function in a try / catch block, or you can (**preferrably**) use node.js [domains](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) to catch the error.

Comment: I'll look into the domain possibility. The entire block in a try catch didn't work for me, probably because it's async. Do you have any idea why this happens tho? Could it be a bug in the Node.js core?

Comment: The Node.JS Documentation does state that using domains to handle unhandledExceptions isn't a very good idea:

"WARNING!  BAD IDEA! The error won't crash the process, but what it does is worse! Though we've prevented abrupt process restarting, we are leaking resources like crazy if this ever happens. This is no better than process.on('uncaughtException')!"

Are you sure this is fine for a https.request? Will I be causing memory leaks?

Comment: Try it like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/Gr2dz/

Comment: A request failing shouldn't cause an issue, but important node processes failing and being catched in a domain without a node restart should be avoided at all cost, and that's why the warning is there, so as to not keep running node if something fails miserably, but this is simply the server not responding, and shouldn't cause any issues.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll have to try this out and wait X hours to see if the error still pops up. Another question: Every time I call the request function I declare a new domain in the d variable, is that fine or should I close the domain somehow?

Comment: You can create a domain on a higher level and use the add() and remove() methods to add and remove stuff, but you have to remove the current iteration only after the request is completed successfully etc.

Comment: Ok, I did some research and understand now :-). One more thing, If you create a domain, and never destroy it, but later I call the function again and create the domain again. Will garbage collecting take care of it, or will I have continuously growing memory usage?

Comment: Not sure, never tried it ?

Comment: Trying it now, will come back with my findings!

Comment: anything new on this?

Comment: If it is running ok and then breaking then it is probably a memory leak issue. Look through and make sure all of your callbacks are returned otherwise it will continue to hold onto its memory allocation and then eventually die like this

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an error-handler for the response.

```
res.on('error', function errorHandler(err) { console.log(err); });
```